# MySQL Convert string to date with milliseconds

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, I would like to convert the following string to a date:

`28/11/17 14:09:04,491592000`

I used the following format in `str_to_date`:

`%d/%m/%y %h:%i:%s,%f`

But this only seems to work when the milliseconds are <= 6 digits long. What if there are more digits in the milliseconds?

Comment: What version of mysql are you using?

Comment: That's "microseconds", not "milliseconds", and there are only 1000000 microseconds in one second.  That number should never have more than six digits, because that would just increment the "seconds" field.

Comment: @larsks I think the OP is using "milliseconds" in a very loose way to mean fractional seconds.

Answer (score 1):

From the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html):

> MySQL 5.7 has fractional seconds support for TIME, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP values, with up to microseconds (6 digits) precision

So if you are using `datetime` to store these values, 6 digits to the right of the decimal point is the greatest possible precision.

In MySQL versions 5.6 and later you can define a column to be `datetime(6)`, which can then hold precision up to microseconds.  There is even a function `MICROSECOND` which can return the microsecond component of a `datetime`.  In earlier versions of MySQL only millisecond precision is available.